# Создание и запись переменной из оператора if в формулу

Tags: javascript, калькулятор

Всем добра и здоровья !
Тружусь над калькулятором. У меня есть диапазоны чисел: 0-6=0, 7-13=1, 14-19=2 ... и т д. Есть поле ввода в котором *вводя* значение из диапазона, должно вставляться в формулу значение присвоенное диапазону 0,1,2 ... и т д. Как это реализовать на примере кода ниже ?

```
var rasstoyanie = document.querySelector('.rasstoyanie').innerHTML = 1; // значение которое вводит пользователь

function rasstoyanieformula() {
    if (0 < rasstoyanie && rasstoyanie <= 6)
        alert("0");
    else if (7 <= rasstoyanie && rasstoyanie <= 13)
        alert("1")
    else if (14 <= rasstoyanie && rasstoyanie <= 19)
        alert("2")    
} // и т д alert я не знаю чем заменить, мне нужно что бы это значение подставлялось в формулу ниже :(
    btn.onclick = function () {

        if (weight.value != '' && vol.value != '') {
            if (load.checked) {
                load.value = 0;
            }
            else {
                load.value = 0;
            }
            if (del.checked) {
                del.value = 50;
            }
            else {
                del.value = 0;
            }
    
            // Вывод формула      
    
            var sum = (weight.value * kg) + (vol.value * kub) + Number(load.value) + + Number(del.value) + (range.value * km) - значение из функции rasstoyanieformula ;
            if (isNaN(sum)) {
                alert('Введите числовое значение');
            } else {
                out.innerHTML = sum;
            }
    
        } else {
            alert('Введите вес и объем груза');
        }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function distanceToRangeId(distance) {
  distance = parseInt(distance);
  if (distance <= 0)
    return -1;
  else if (distance <= 6)
    return 0;
  else if (distance <= 13)
    return 1;
  else if (distance <= 19)
    return 2;
  else
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, функция может быть такой:

```js
function rasstoyanieformula(num) {
    if (0 < num && num <= 6)
        return 0;
    if (7 <= num && num <= 13)
        return 1;
    if (14 <= num && num <= 19)
        return 2; 
}
```

А получать значение можно так:

```js
var sum = (weight.value * kg) + (vol.value * kub) + Number(load.value) + + Number(del.value) +
  (range.value * km) - rasstoyanieformula(document.querySelector('.rasstoyanie').innerHTML);
```